# Mongoose collection.insert continueOnError, inserted documents not passed in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a model from a schema which has a unique index.
I tried to use Model.collection.insert() to insert multiple documents.
The data may have some duplicate documents, so I used continueOnError in option.
I checked the shell, the data seems to be inserted normally, but in the callback, the documents passed is null.

```
Model.collection.insert(data.slice(0, 3), {
  continueOnError: 1
}, function(err, documents) {
  console.log(arguments); // { 0: null, 1: [{...}, {...}, {...}] }
});
```

then

```
Model.collection.insert(data.slice(0, 5), {
  continueOnError: 1
}, function(err, documents) {
  console.log(arguments); // { 0: error message, 1: null }
});
```

I just want to know how many documents I have insert successfully. How can I do that?

Comment: what does documents variable returns, on console logging?

Comment: it's in my question already, first time it's an array of 3 elements, second time it's null

Comment: you are logging `arguments`, while the function is returning `documents`

Comment: AFAIK "The arguments object is a local variable available within all functions. You can refer to a function's arguments within the function by using the arguments object. This object contains an entry for each argument passed to the function, the first entry's index starting at 0."